# Change font color in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the font of all the text that is in violet to black in all sheets on my Excel document.
I've found something that change the color based on a condition :

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' modify to your sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow 
        If ......... Then -> here is where the condition will go in my opinion 
            .Range("F" & i).Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            .Range("F" & i).Font.Color = vbBlack
        End If
    Next i        
End With
```

Then i've found the RGB and ColorIndex of color of the text that I want to found

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A13").font.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
```

or with the colorIndex

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A14").font.ColorIndex = 19
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: `If .Range("F" & i).Font.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160) Then`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what should I put on the else condition ? I can continue the iteration somehow ? or if i just put if......then....endif will work ?

Comment: remove the `.Range("F" & i).Font.Color = vbRed` line and the `Else` line.  No Else is Needed.

Comment: Sadly the macro dont work :(

Comment: what does `don't work` Mean?  does it error? if so on which line and what is the error.  Does it run but does nothing?  If so check to make sure the color you are looking for is correct and that it is not colored because of conditional formatting.

Comment: The code run but does nothing, i've found 3 colorindex for violet but when try to use these values the code is not working, the code loop but it does nothing.

Comment: I've found that with `With Worksheets("Feuil1")
    If .Range("A2").Font.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160) Then
        .Range("A2").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End With`
I can change the violet color of the A2 cell so the color its correct, that means that the loop is not working. I don't know if this can help

Comment: Your code is looking in Column `F` not `A`.

Comment: I see (i'm beginner in vba as you can see).... Now I understand, how can i select colums from `A` to `Q` ?